# MongoDB limit() and sort() Optimization

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to understand why this is happening:

```
db.items.find({uid: {$in:[34, 54, 53,1,2,3,5,6,7]} }).limit(40).sort({_id:-1}).explain()
```

returns me:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_-1_uid_1 multi",
"nscanned" : 167,
"nscannedObjects" : 40,
"n" : 40,
...
```

However, without the sort

```
db.items.find({uid: {$in:[34, 54, 53,1,2,3,5,6,7]} }).limit(40).explain()
```

returns me:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor uid_1 multi",
"nscanned" : 40,
"nscannedObjects" : 40,
"n" : 40,
...
```

So what I dont get is, why when I add the sort, it scans more documents? I am sorting by *id, also I have this index to try to improve things "*_id_-1_uid_1" , but still it scans a lot of documents.

This is a huge issue in my case, because this is my local database, so just a few documents are been scanned, however in my live site, I have millons of documents been scanned for a reason which I dont know what it is.

Can anyone explain me what is going on?

Comment: What other indexes do you have? Perhaps try {uid:1, id:-1} instead...

Comment: I have tried both index, {uid:1, id:-1}  and {id:-1,uid:1} ! and no success at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present (2012/3/14), this is an unresolved bug :

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3310

Comment: This bug is fixed as of the 2.6.x branch.